# Cannot submit Html Forms when combine 2 view pages together in MVC

Tags: javascript, html, forms, model-view-controller, onclick

In my application used have two View pages "AddHardware" and "EditHardware", they are used to create a html forms and add/edit information about hardwares.

Now I was working on combine this two pages together to reduce code duplicates, I'm using:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEditInvHardware", "InvHardware", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", id = "HardwareForm" }))
    {         
        if (Model != null && Model.InvHardwareID > 0)
        {
                <div style="float:right; padding-inline:12px;">
                    <input type="button" value="Update" id="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="onSubmit()" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif" />
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="history.go(-1);" href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif" />
                </div>
                <hr width="100%" style="border:hidden" />

        }
        else
        {
                <div style="float:right; padding-inline:12px;">                     
                    <input type="button" value="Save" id="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="onSubmit()" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif" />
                    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "InvHardware", "InvHardware", new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg", @style = "font-size: 15px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif" })

                </div>
                <hr width="100%" style="border:hidden" />
        }


    }
```

My javascript code are below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        SetDateLabelsPurchaseOrLease();

        $("#AcquisitionTypeID").change(function () {
            SetDateLabelsPurchaseOrLease();
        });

        function SetDateLabelsPurchaseOrLease() {
            myAcqType = $('#AcquisitionTypeID').val();
            if (myAcqType == 1) {
                var myStartDate = "Warranty Start Date";
                var myEndDate = "Warranty End Date";
            }
            if (myAcqType == 2) {
                var myStartDate = "Leased Start Date";
                var myEndDate = "Leased End Date";
            }
            $('#LabelForWL_StartDate').html(myStartDate);
            $('#LabelForWL_EndDate').html(myEndDate);
        }

        $("#WL_StartDate").attr("autocomplete", "off");
        $(function () {
            $("#WL_StartDate").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                onSelect: function (selected) {
                    $("#WL_EndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
                },
            });
        });

        $("#WL_EndDate").attr("autocomplete", "off");
        $(function () {
            $("#WL_EndDate").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                onSelect: function (selected) {
                    $("#WL_StartDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
                },
            });
        });

        $("#ReceivedDate").attr("autocomplete", "off");
        $(function () {
            $("#ReceivedDate").datepicker({
                maxDate: '0',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
            });
        });

        $('#departments-data-table').DataTable({
            columnDefs: [{
                "targets": [6],
                "searchable": false,
                "targets": [6],
                "orderable": false
            }]
        });
    });
    function onSubmit() {
        var myAcqType = $('#AcquisitionTypeID').val();
        Alert("myAcqType", myAcqType);
        if (PassValidations() == true) {
            $('#HardwareForm').submit();               
        }
        //else do nothing
    }
    function PassValidations() {
        try {
            alert("Begin PassValidations", "");
            ClearErrorCodesOnPage();

            var startDate = $('#WL_StartDate').val(),
                endDate = $('#WL_EndDate').val(),
                recDate = $('#ReceivedDate').val(),
                amount = $('#Amount').val(),
                sdate = new Date(startDate),
                edate = new Date(endDate),
                rdate = new Date(recDate);

            var myB5 = ValidateDateTextBox("ReceivedDate", "Received Date");
            var myB6 = ValidateDateTextBox("WL_StartDate", "Start Date");
            var myB7 = ValidateDateTextBox("WL_EndDate", "End Date");
            var myB8 = ValidateTwoDateTextBox("WL_StartDate", "WL_EndDate", "Start Date");
            var myB9 = ValidateNoFutureDateTextBox("ReceivedDate", "Received Date");

            var myB1 = ValidateBlankTextBox("Amount", "Amount");
            var myB2 = ValidateBlankTextBox("ReceivedDate", "Received Date");
            var myB3 = ValidateBlankTextBox("WL_StartDate", "Start Date");
            var myB4 = ValidateBlankTextBox("WL_EndDate", "End Date");

            var myB10 = ValidateBlankTextBox("PONumber", "PO Number");
            var myB11 = ValidateBlankTextBox("Equipment", "Equipment");
            var myB12 = ValidateBlankTextBox("SerialNum", "Serial #");
            var myB13 = ValidateBlankTextBox("HardwareModel", "Model");
            var myB14 = ValidateBlankTextBox("AssetNum", "Asset #");
            var myb15 = ValidateBlankTextBox("Manufacturer", "Manufacturer");

            if (
                myB1
                && myB2
                && myB3
                && myB4
                && myB5
                && myB6
                && myB7
                && myB8
                && myB9
                && myB10
                && myB11
                && myB12
                && myB13
                && myB14
                && myb15
            ) {
                alert("Pass PassValidations", "true");
                return true;
            } else {
                //alert("Failed");
                alert("Not Pass PassValidations", "false");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (err) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
        }
    }

    function ClearErrorCodesOnPage() {
        alert("begin Clear Codes");
        $('#errorAmount').html("");
        $("#errorAmount").css("display", "none");
        $('#errorReceivedDate').html("");
        $("#errorReceivedDate").css("display", "none");
        $('#errorWL_StartDate').html("");
        $("#errorWL_StartDate").css("display", "none");
        $('#errorWL_EndDate').html("");
        $("#errorWL_EndDate").css("display", "none");

        $('#errorPONumber').html("");
        $("#errorPONumber").css("display", "none");
        $('#errorEquipment').html("");
        $("#errorEquipment").css("display", "none");
        $('#errorSerialNum').html("");
        $("#errorSerialNum").css("display", "none");
        $('#errorHardwareModel').html("");
        $("#errorHardwareModel").css("display", "none");
        $('#errorAssetNum').html("");
        $("#errorAssetNum").css("display", "none");
        $('#errorManufacturer').html("");
        $("#errorManufacturer").css("display", "none");
        alert("end Clear Codes");
    }

    
</script>
```

Before combine them together, the submit button for both page are works fine, but now only Edit -> submit button works, when I click Add -> sumbit nothing happened, is that because I made some duplicate problems in javascript?
Thanks!

Comment: ID's HAVE to be unique. It's unclear from your code but I'm guessing the 'add' part is the top `if()` statement in the form. You have two elements with an id of `submit`. How is the code meant to know what id is pressed?

Comment: Hi @JamesS, thanks for your comments, I changed the id of these elements, but it still not working...